# Valid statistical test for difference in age between two time points (for a cohort with additional membership)

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, observational-study, age

The question at hand is whether the membership for an organisation has 'aged' from 2016 to 2021.
[image]

2021 membership is made up of 2016 members who continued to 2021 and new members from 2016 and 2021. Also a proportion of 2016 members have left. Age was not normally distributed so non-parametric tests under consideration. My initial thought is to test for a change in mean differences Mann Whitney U test considered the best to test the median of the difference of ages between the 2016 sample and the 2021 sample. But given that the 2016 cohort are also included in the 2021 sample, I'm concerned that this would not meet the assumption of independence required. Also, I have a concern that the natural change in age of 5 years for the 'continuing cohort' across the two time points might artificially inflate statistical power (because of doubling in n) or the estimates of the median of differences in age.

Are these issues solved by separating out the cohort and identify the two independent samples as the 2016 members who will continue to 2021 ('will retain') and the sample of members who were cumulatively added to the 2021 sample ('additional')? Or is this overcomplicating things?

[image]

Other approaches I have seen before looks at the proportion in the two samples older than a specific age (>= 65 or >= 55), and perhaps then chi square tests for homogeneity. But this approach loses some of the information I would have thought and maybe more appropriate when the data does not provide each of the individuals' ages.

Comment: Can you explain "organization has 'aged'". What is exactly are you trying to test?  My question is if not members left and no members joined then the organization aged by 5 years. So if you are looking the average age now to average age then, I would treat it as 2 independent groups and use the Wilicoxon test.  Your references to $\chi^{2}$ is also valid but answers a different question.

Comment: Only the members who continued from 2016 to 2021 aged by 5 yrs (retention). A proportion from 2016 left (attrition) and in 2021 new members came in (addition). So as a group, are the 2021 members older than the 2016 membership? Wilcoxon test requires independent samples no? The retention portion in 2021 are from the same sample in 2016. Hence my concern. Hope Ive explained this better.

Comment: If your hypothesis is the age of the 2021 group is the same as the age of 2016 group then you have 2 distinct population and it doesn’t matter that some or all the members in 2021 were members in 2016.  You are testing if the age has changed or not.  The independence rule doesn’t count in the situation I mentioned above, it could be important if you have not hypothesis.

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you. Looks like I just needed clarification on the independence rule.